# CentOS 7 で PHP 7 を使う

Tags: php, centos, yum

CentOS 7 に Apache と、PHP 7 をインストールしたのですが、php -vで確認してみると

> PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov  6 2016 00:29:02)
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

PHP のバージョンは 7 ではなく 5.4.16 でした。
Ubuntu では `a2dismod php5` コマンドを使い切り替えたんですが、CentOS でのやり方がわかりません。
教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

パッケージインストールであれば、CentOS の場合はリポジトリを追加してアップデートする形になります。

PHP 7 のパッケージが利用できるリポジトリは複数ありますが、特に要件がなければ Remi's Repository がよいでしょう。

```
yum install epel-release
yum --disablerepo=epel update epel-release
yum install http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70
yum update php
```

Comment: yum install yum-utils を実行すると、パスが全部切れているみたいなんですが・・・

Comment: epel-release のバージョンが古いせいですね。
以下を実行してみるとどうでしょうか。

    `yum --disablerepo=epel update epel-release`

Comment: 読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: ftp.riken.jp
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: ftp.riken.jp
No packages marked for update

と返ってきます。

Comment: yum install epel-release　実行すると最新バージョンといわれますね

Comment: epel-release は最新なんですね。では `yum install yum-utils` で表示されるエラーはどのような内容なのでしょうか。

Comment: ちなみに `yum update php --enablerepo=remi-php70` でもアップデートできるかと思います。

Comment: yum install yum-utils　を実行するとインストールが始まりました。

Comment: yum update php --enablerepo=remi-php70　を実行したら、バージョン７．０．１４に変わりました。

Comment: 一度 `yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70` を実行してリポジトリを有効にできたら、以降は --enablerepo オプションを付けなくても大丈夫です。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。